# How to perform foreach loop in same order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I am getting the array from client side as

```
var arr = [{'url':'www.google.com'},{'url':'www.fb.com'}]
```

I want to assign it to a string as

```
var urls = www.google.com,www.facebook.com
```

Which I did but I am getting the index reverse like below

```
var urls = www.facebook.com,www.google.com
```

My code:

```
duis.arr(function(v,i){
   urls = v.url + ','+urls;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=control):

```js
var arr = [{'url':'www.google.com'},{'url':'www.fb.com'}];
var urls = arr.map(url => url.url).join(',');
console.log(urls);
```

Updated for the new requirements from the comments:

```js
var arr = [{'url_name':'a','name':'b'},{'url_name':'c','name':'a'}];
var urls = arr.map(url => url.url_name).reverse().join(',');
console.log(urls);
```

Comment: Hi str,this is my actual array can u please edit your answer

Comment: var arr = [{'url_name':'a','name':'b'},{'url_name':'c','name':'a'}]

Comment: i want urls = a,c;

Comment: @MMR So you want the value of `name`? Why is the order reversed?

Comment: soryy,I edited my comment .I want urls like last one first and so on ...i.e urls= c,a;.i just want url_name no need for name field.

Comment: @MMR I extended the answer to your new requirements.

Comment: @MMR: *".I want urls like last one first and so on"* That's the opposite of what your question asks.

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse your existing concatenation and handle the special first iteration *(I have no idea what the `arr` method is, but you said you were getting the result you want backward, so)*:

```
duis.arr(function(v,i){ // Whatever `arr` is -- I would have expected `forEach`
   urls = urls ? urls + ',' + v.url : v.url;
});
```

Or you can use `reduce`:

```
urls = duis.reduce(function(p, v) {
    return p ? p + ',' + v.url : v.url;
}, '');
```

Example:

```js
var duis = [{
  'url': 'www.google.com'
}, {
  'url': 'www.fb.com'
}];
var urls = duis.reduce(function(p, v) {
  return p ? p + ',' + v.url : v.url;
}, '');
console.log(urls);
```

If you have to support obsolete browsers like IE8 (as many still do), a simple `for` loop would be best:

```
var urls = duis[0].url;
for (var i = 1; i < duis.length; ++i) {
  urls += ',' + duis[i].url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map)** and **[join](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/join)**:

```
 const arr = [{'url':'www.google.com'},{'url':'www.fb.com'}];
 const urls = arr.map(el => el.url).join(',')
 console.log(urls) // "www.google.com,www.fb.com"
```

[Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=%20%20%20%20%20const%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%7B'url'%3A'www.google.com'%7D%2C%7B'url'%3A'www.fb.com'%7D%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20const%20newArr%20%3D%20arr.map(el%20%3D%3E%20el.url).join('%2C')%0A%20%20%20%20%20console.log(newArr)%20%2F%2F%20%22www.google.com%2Cwww.fb.com%22)

Answer (score 0):

`map` and `join` could be nice solution, but for better performance, just loop the array :

```
var urls = arr && arr.shift().url;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    urls = urls + ',' + arr[i].url
}
```

Comment: better*. looping once than looping twice.